# How much current should I pass through battery to break through sulphate deposits?

Tags: battery-charging, battery-chemistry

I recovered an aged SLA from the pile dated 2003 marked 6V 4.5AH. It has .97V in it. As I recollect, thumb rule for a charging current would be about 500mA at 7V or better.

A breadboarded LM317 may be capable of doing this.

Given it's age, should the battery be given a high current jolt initially to break through any sulphate buildup? How long should this be maintained? How does one confirm desulphation success?

Comment: VTC - This question seems more like an electronic device usage question than as a design related question. For this reason it is off topic here. In addition it seems like the subject of desulphation of a battery is something that you should be able to learn a lot more about with a little web searching.

Comment: Pretty unlikley you will be able to revive it. What I do is make sure the water level is high enough, apply a low voltage, say your 7 V until it starts to take current. After that charge it fully to 14.4 V and let it absorb for hours, preferably overnight. After that, make sure you have good ventilation and push the voltage to 18 V until you get a good boubble. Don't boil off too much water. Refill with water and check how much life you get from it. Probably not much. What do you have access to?

Comment: @winny it is a 6v battery

Comment: @PlasmaHH Oh! Then divide all my voltages by two.

Comment: i don't think you should boil an SLA, and there's no way to check/adjust the "water"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extensive experience on desulphating lead acid batteries.

The success rate depends greatly upon the level of contamination in days or months and after 1yr, the success rate depends greatly on the resting voltage and ambient temperature which both cause  aggressive  degradation and plate erosion/diffusion.

> The design in electrical terms must excite the piezo-electric effect to vibrate crystal growth and slowly break down and settle to the bottom without self heating which aggravates the cause.

You must have an idea or know how to compute and measure Pd with pulses with a model of the battery condition before and after and can minimize \$E=I^2*ESR*t(PW50) *f \$ f=rep. rate  for 50% Pulse Width by knowing the approximate temperature rise of the plate junctions, not the case, you can restore a dead battery that worked a month ago. Only low degraded or high quality motive power flooded batteries and ceramic 230kg 2V cells can be rejuvenated after 2 years to 100% . Others will be a small portion of this.

The battery ESR is a combination of SoC and sulphation which may be >100x greater initially so sensing V/I pulses will tell you if it is improving.  I have tested 25KHz 10A flyback pulse 1W types and have seen test results on 1kA pulse rejuvenator with CPU automation for automotive batteries work well up to 1.5yrs of aging.

Comment: Ergo A battery that may have been abandoned for over a decade is a poor candidate?

Comment: Pulse 10A for a month 1W  then let us know

Comment: Seriously, now?

Comment: Or buy a reputable desulphenator that operates in tandem on float CV 3.6V. I seen test results on NiCd, NiMH, PbHSO4 and Li-Ion and verified the results from a Test Engineers perspective. Results vary with conditions any age of undervoltage condition affects probability of success.  You can’t always expect to under-achieved lifespan in capacity but you can get 50% more life with active pulse balancing in strings from my test results

Comment: In motive power batteries the s.g. Is the best indicator of ESR and both are improved with continuous, narrow ,fast risetime ,pulse charging attached to charger. We made 10k units / batch for Solartech who sold his ‘Bic lighter’ approach company for millions, while a “blow torch” approach is viable but more dangerous.